# Need paypal authorization for (sandbox) digital good transaction, paypal support hasn't answered me

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement Paypal's Digital Goods payment on my application, and after a little bit of research and coding, I had everything almost up and running, the only problem was this error:

> SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: You are
>   not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.Short
>   Error Message: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See
>   additional error messages for details.Error Code: 10004 Error Severity
>   Code: Error

After a little googling, it seems that I need some sort of authorization to use the Digital Goods API, even on sandbox (which is just stupid, if you ask me). I tried posting on x.com, private messaging paypal staff on x.com and the usual support channel on paypal.com, and have got absolutely no answer whatsoever (it has been 1 week since I sent these). Anyone got any idea how to get the authorization? My project has been dead on it's tracks for a week, since I need to integrate paypal to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be how to get Customer Support from paypal to send you the authorization.  I don't believe you are using the correct channel, however.

Try sending them a message via https://ppmts.custhelp.com/ which is reserved for merchants.  If you set the urgency to "some business impact" (which it is) they'll likely respond rather quickly.  I had a similar issue with a related service that was resolved in about 24 hours.

Comment: I feel like I cheated StackOverflow a bit by not submitting a programming question, but I'm a bit desperate at this point. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion, I didn't know about the MTS. I've sent a request, let's hope it work this time. Thanks!